# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number' within constructor definition

Tags: typescript, types, constructor, constructor-overloading

> Issue

The parameter value `maxORhealth` prompts the following error; in VS Code:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

... and unsure how to navigate around this error.

> Class Definition

```js
    class Vitals implements IVitals
    {
        vitals!: 
        { 
            HealthValue:    number | undefined; 
            StrengthValue?: number | undefined;
            ManaValue?:     number | undefined; 
            StaminaValue?:  number | undefined; 
            IntelectValue?: number | undefined; 
            TuneValue?:     number | undefined; 
        };

        /// CONSTRUCTORS
        constructor()
        constructor(maxORhealth: number)
        constructor(maxORhealth: number, maxORstrength: number)
        constructor(maxORhealth: number, 
                    maxORstrength: number, 
                    mana: number, 
                    stamina: number, 
                    intelect: number, 
                    tune: number)
        constructor(maxORhealth?: number, 
                    maxORstrength?: number, 
                    mana?: number, 
                    stamina?: number, 
                    intelect?: number, 
                    tune?: number)
    {
           if (Number.isInteger(maxORhealth) && maxORstrength === undefined && mana === undefined)
           {
                this.vitals.HealthValue   = getRandomInt(maxORhealth);  <= Error .ts(2345)
                this.vitals.StrengthValue = getRandomInt(maxORhealth);
                this.vitals.ManaValue     = getRandomInt(maxORhealth); 
                this.vitals.StaminaValue  = getRandomInt(maxORhealth); 
                this.vitals.IntelectValue = getRandomInt(maxORhealth); 
                this.vitals.TuneValue     = getRandomInt(maxORhealth); 
           }
           else if (Number.isInteger(maxORhealth) && maxORstrength === undefined)
           {
                this.vitals.HealthValue   = maxORhealth; 
                this.vitals.StrengthValue = getRandomInt(maxORstrength!);
                this.vitals.ManaValue     = getRandomInt(maxORstrength!); 
                this.vitals.StaminaValue  = getRandomInt(maxORstrength!); 
                this.vitals.IntelectValue = getRandomInt(maxORstrength!); 
                this.vitals.TuneValue     = getRandomInt(maxORstrength!); 
            }
            else
            {
                this.vitals.HealthValue   = maxORhealth; 
                this.vitals.StrengthValue = maxORstrength;
                this.vitals.ManaValue     = mana; 
                this.vitals.StaminaValue  = stamina; 
                this.vitals.IntelectValue = intelect; 
                this.vitals.TuneValue     = tune; 
            }
        }
    }
```

> Desired Affect

I would like to have three `constructors` for this class, as follows:

```js
    constructor()
    constructor(maxORhealth: number)
    constructor(maxORhealth: number, maxORstrength: number)
    constructor(maxORhealth: number, maxORstrength: number, mana: number, stamina: number, intelect: number, tune: number)
```

... with (hopefully) a practical (none overly JS fancy) solution.

- Cheers, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error originates from this statement:

```js
Number.isInteger(maxORhealth)
```

`maxORhealth` is of type `number | undefined`. Because it's an optional argument to the constructor, it can be either a `number` or `undefined`.

`Number.isInteger` is typed to only accept a parameter of type `number`. Therefore TypeScript complains because `maxORhealth` could also be a number.

---

To fix this you can do one of two things. You can introduce an additional check for `undefined` like this:

```js
if (maxORhealth !== undefined && Number.isInteger(maxORhealth) && maxORstrength === undefined && mana === undefined) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQEoEMwBM4C2AkmFABRYBOyAXImCAQEaqUCUdDzriA3opXQhKSACwAmANyIAvgFgAUIogAbLAGd1iAGowoWFVpgEADitQFUpLUV37DixE76PnbgG56D6gIR1Xbk78AYFuABKoBlAAFtoGIKh0zlwslIgAPojguKjAMGCouNIhoU4AylCCYMgxcSoJAPycjKkZWXi5+YWSJaUAsjhYdY1JyS08mdmdBUWIvaEVWAT5Q-GoTU4pE+05eTPFCqWBJFCo5tDD683caZMde91zh0fOACrgqJcbblu3O9OPeayHpKZ6hAD0kMQAGEAPIAOTKrwwAFVoa9YRgykCIAh1JUQNA4JQyGwcXiCUSSQQsAAPTHRSIqGLXVJksGBXFgfGUQlQYlkGn0jCMqLRVmsAA0iCFmJ5Vhq4vo43Y5O5lP51LpDKZLOVN2lQJezllGHl1T1v0NHONoRpYCwEso1ttL3xSxWTpdrtK+VO5ygXqePtKUA+TvZRy5PL5AtNouZ0Q2VuDIcCpvNiuTKu9aZNg2zBtTeac7uWDsLqVzJb9Z1Q0ErUuLJbDBUbqo5vCNThgwEQgu1It10UQPgAvGP-g9cIgAGSzxDwlUAOhg6hOqDQWuFCZibDnC4zlQVMUQE8nU2nB5lgzPE6nXVwkeNXZttpia+Xnns6mXETFlzOJOaCYDg+DEKQA47sObAgnmH6-t+3jLhUVSKoBwHoNgeCECcUE6mKsHdqECFfl4hjLgMDqAW4mGgThEHkPGMEHPB0SfkhFGLOWqz1KgTh0dh4F4cxhGsWmpGcb+G4BhhKBYWBuGQaJiawc2rqSeRv7vAUNFAfJ9HCcpg67tEanEfIb6BGc6j8b2-Yqae44Xvcj7XkuNyruupCbqw+FDoR15Hmhp7ng+MzPi8r5sRxWl-sOemTo50TiSGmk-ihx4WrEaxngZQlKUxg6ZjEPhEVZLzpchVG8QkgSCYpjH+SV0RlalPpVVx+g8TRDUMSJxVZYqbXqe+7GIXFMn1lAckgQVTXBSerXmRVRyddpHx6QJ+WNQNwotSNxGyEdNmoEd0USeNZEZf+iaJTe0Fiu1GlXVJmUhTlfF5Yt2VwZdsUZTVW3fYMz1jQDyHcSsvWIGWKxg8a63LlNFy5ZOtYBgjlWvXFOmfLltGIK2qBY24llHOTzgyEAA)

Alternatively, considering `Number.isInteger(undefined)` is handled properly and just returns `false`, you could also convince TypeScript that it's okay anyway. To do that you can use the non-null assertion postfix `!` operator:

```js
Number.isInteger(maxORhealth!)
//                          ^
```

This operator tells TypeScript that `maxORhealth` is not `undefined` and not `null`.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQEoEMwBM4C2AkmFABRYBOyAXImCAQEaqUCUdDzriA3opXQhKSACwAmANyIAvgFgAUIogAbLAGd1iAGowoWFVpgEADitQFUpLUV37DixE76PnbgG56D6gIR1Xbk78AYFuABKoBlAAFtoGIKh0zlwslIgAPojguKjAMGCouNIhoU4AylCCYMgxcSoJAPycjKkZWXi5+YWSJaUAsjhYdY1JyS08mdmdBUWIvaEVWAT5Q-GoTU4pE+05eTPFCqWBJFCo5tDD683caZMde91zh0fOACrgqJcbblu3O9OPeayHpKZ6hAD0kMQAGEAPIAOTKrwwAFVoa9YRgykCIAh1JUQNA4JQyGwcXiCUSSQQsAAPTHRSIqGLXVJksGBXFgfGUQlQYlkGn0jCMqLRVmsAA0iCFmJ5Vhq4vo43Y5O5lP51LpDKZLOVN2lQJezllGHl1T1v0NHONoRpYCwEso1ttL3xSxWTpdrtK+VO5ygXqePtKUA+TvZRy5PL5AtNouZ0Q2VuDIcCpvNiuTKu9aZNg2zBtTeac7uWDsLqVzJb9Z1Q0ErUuLJbDBUbqo5vCNThgwEQZHhKoAdDB1CdUGgtcKEzEfGxEAAyBcy7VmyoKmKIAC8O-+D1wi+X9qw293U33keNXZttpio6Hnns6iHETFl2cW5Q6GweEIJ0Fq4ztEc4gnmd7Po+3hDhUVSKu+n5oJgOD4MQpAAdOurAWwoFpuBD5eIYQ4DA675uAh37IX+aHxphIHNq6eGQYRizlqs9SoE45FIb+qHkDRYp0d2oSMQRz7jgG8FftxKH-vxiaCTexoiU+Q7vAUpEflJP4ydRgG0dh9GhPIiluGc6gcb2-aDjcI5jqQE6sOhOoCfOS4rsKmabjun7nl0uCXi815gdE95Mc+r6Jhpn5yTEBzBaFonQeuFqxGs25aZRvFOWusGzthQmBMpUHEWxCSBFx2lUXxq6eVhcW4SFEGJSxKykRVmWyTVyWKgp8VNSp4n1lAkmIZVWUZt1eX1SGRWEWpnxpWRGU8Z1HmTXVhlGQVZmoAVQUNQlKkRbUi3pTF0TTT6s3PjBG6pexZ1dblF0FW411EYMGmcSuDqXQxjX4SpLUkYtn5lisf23gDYVDoNFxpZ+tYBpDSnQ4l81felraoCjgTGUc+PODIQA)

Comment: Cheers mate, that's it. Thanks for the feedback!